# Kali linux disappeared from boot menu after installing windows 10

Tags: linux, kali-linux, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader

Earlier I had dual boot with windows 10 and kali linux. Boot menu was displayed by kali. I reinstalled windows 10 due to some issue but now system directly boots to windows 10. No boot menu is being displayed. I tried to enable boot menu from cmd. After restart windows boot menu was displayed with 2 options- Windows 10 and Fast Mode.

I think that after reinstalling windows 10, mbr was replaced by windows 10. This can be a reason why kali is not showing in boot menu. I tried searching for a solution but didn't find anything helpful.

Any suggestions on how to solve this pls?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to boot into Linux (I prefer GRML from grml.org booted from an USB drive) and to re-install the boot menu from there:

1. boot into GRML
2. mount the KALI partition, e.g. to /media/username/kali
3. bind-mount some system directories: `for dir in proc dev sys ; do mount -o bind /$dir /media/username/kali/$dir ; done`
4. chroot into KALI Linux: `chroot /media/username/kali`
5. re-install the Grub menu: `update-grub`
6. it may be necessary th write the bootloader: `grub-install /dev/sda` (the name of the SD/HDD with Kali/Windows)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I used [boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) on live usb, it worked. If you don't want to go into terminal and commands then this is the best option.